# What would be the AWG (American Wire Gauge) standard for my wire 1 x 0.75 rm?

Tags: wire, calculation, awg

I have been trying to figure out my wire gauge standard in AWG format. I bought a coil (100 meters) of wire and the info written on the package is: **1 x 0.75 rm**. I understand the 1 in here represents the number of cores, which is single core / 1 core. But I do not understand the 0.75 rm part. I need to know the AWG standard of the cable I bought.

I found online that, **rm = round multi wire conductor** and the standard formula for calculating the rm is also provided online, **rm = A x number of strands**, where **A = (π x D^2)/4**, **D = diameter of a single strand**.

I do not know the diameter of a single strand and I do not have slide calipers to measure that. The shopkeeper told me this coil is known as **25/76** and I counted that there are **25 strands** inside the wire. All I know that I needed to buy a 18 AWG wire coil. What is the rm calculation for 18 AWG wire of a single core (1 core)?

Comment: could it be 0.75mm2?

Comment: It's odd. 0.75 mm^2 wire does correspond to AWG 18. But if it has 23 strands, the individual strands should be AWG 32, not 76, so I don't understand that part of what the shopkeeper told you. FWIW, the diameter of AWG 18 wire is almost exactly 1 mm, so maybe you can verify what you got that way.

Comment: Are you sure you're not misreading something else (like mm?) as "rm"?

Comment: I think this picture is going to help you - https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-b8ba98d1404ce79f938ff96701b897f5-lq

Comment: I just made some edits due to the strand count. I believe it's 25. According to my calculation, the diameter of a single strand in my wire is around 0.19 mm. But I do not see such measurement in AWG and also the nearest value is AWG 32, in the AWG chart from wikipedia. I am very much confused about AWG diameter size in the chart, whether it represents the diameter of the whole wire ( including total number of cores) or just a single strand.